# IntelliJ Hebrew support

Tags: utf-8, intellij-idea, hebrew

IntelliJ doesn't support the Hebrew language, and makes the work with it very frustrating and hard. I've searched the internet for some plugin which would help integrating Hebrew with IntelliJ, but couldn't find any. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-to-left text rendering in the IntelliJ text editor is not something that can be implemented as a plugin. The good news is that we (JetBrains) are working on RTL support right now, and you can already try [a prototype version](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5810#comment=27-924802).